# How to cancel all local notifications when app is deleted from background not from device

Tags: iphone, localnotification

I want to cancel all local notifications when app deleted from background, not from Device. 
 I know this is

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

but my Question is where should i pass it to fire event when application terminates from background.

I called inside `applicationWillTerminateFromBackground` but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply check to see if the app is in the background, and if it is, not fire the notifications.

Comment: SevenBits :- but my Requirment is to get Alarm in foreground as well as background that's why i can't stop notification in background.